# SQLite gives me an error near VALUES, what do I do?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to select all entries from the table that have `user_id = 0` and `type` that I can give as a parameter.

My code is:

```py
get_all_parking_by_type = 'SELECT * FROM Parking WHERE type = ? and user_id = 0 VALUES (?)'
cursor.execute(get_all_parking_by_type, ('guest'))
guests = cursor.fetchall()
```

And the error is:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error

It's probably something stupid but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation for the database that you're using to see the correct syntax for a select statement.

Comment: What do you think `VALUES` means in a `SELECT` query?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what that statement is supposed to mean. Why is there a random `VALUES` at the end of the statement, what is it supposed to do? `VALUES` isn't a statement by itself. What's wrong with just the `SELECT`, why does that not do what you need? Why do you have two parameters in the statement (or is it two statements?) but only pass one parameter in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes here:

- There is no use for the `VALUES`-syntax, at least it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with it; just leave it out
- The parameter as `('guest')` is not actually a tuple but a string inside useless parentheses. You probably meant `('guest', )`.

Try

```py
get_all_parking_by_type = 'SELECT * FROM Parking WHERE type = ? and user_id = 0'
# Notice the comma after `'guest'`
cursor.execute(get_all_parking_by_type, ('guest', ))
guests = cursor.fetchall()
```